# Expo Router Project Structuring

Tags: react-native, expo

Need guidance on project organization: I'm working on an expo project and aiming to have distinct sections for signed-in and signed-out users, as well as an onboarding process. How would you recommend structuring the project. This is what I have in mind but I'm not sure if this follows the standard or is good for the long run.

```
/main -- screens if user is signed in
   - layout.tsx
   - index.tsx, user.tsx, messages.tsx
   /{username}
      - layout.tsx
      - editProfile.tsx
      - settings.tsx
     - ...
   /component -- screens to be used only in /main
      - layout.tsx
/auth -- screens if user is signed out
   - layout.tsx
   - signUp.tsx
   - signIn.tsx
/onboarding -- screens triggered only once after sign up
   - layout.tsx
```